# WARNING: Tryin g to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, html

Hello everybody i need your help. I don't know where is my mistake on this coding can you help me to solve it . This is the code that I got wrong

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>
<?php
  echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'];  
?> 

<i class="caret"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-user icon-large"></i><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'];  ?> <i class="caret"></i></a>

Comment: Effectively `$row` is not an `array` and is instead `$row = null;` So whatever is declaring `$row` is not retrieving the expected value. Possibly a database query that has no results.